# Getting the first author in a pandoc template (Rmarkdown)

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc

I am currently creating my own pandoc template for Rmarkdown (outputting html). I want my report to show a footer containing the title and **first author's name**.

Reading the [pandoc manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html), I saw that it is possible to use a pipe to get the first element of an array (`var/first`). So having the header:

```yaml
title: "My Report"
author:
- "Jane Doe"
- "John Doe"
```

I tried to do the following in the template:

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-content">
    <div class="footer-title">
      <h3>$title$</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-author">
      <h3>$author/first$</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I got as error in the author line:

```sh
"template" (line 96, column 24):
unexpected "/"
expecting "." or "$"
```

Please note that the pandoc version used by rmarkdown is **2.3.1**.

Is there a different way to accomplish that?

Comment: that template syntax was introduced in a later pandoc version.... so try updating.. https://pandoc.org/installing.html

Comment: Min version for this feature is pandoc 2.10.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a small Lua filter to get just the first author:

```lua
function Meta (meta)
  local firstauthor = meta.author.t == 'MetaList'
    and meta.author[1]
    or meta.author
  meta.firstauthor = firstauthor
  return meta
end
```

You can then use `$firstauthor$` in your template. See [here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/docs/articles/lua-filters.html#lua-filter) for a brief discussion of Lua filters and how to use them.